# Nothing is getting when I hit the url of admin in magento after successfully installing the magento using composer

Tags: magento2

[this is the url for /magento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRMrH.png)

[this is the url for /magento/admin_as5lhc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mINAM.png)

After successfully installing the magento using composer I'am getting blank page when I hit the admin url.
I'am unable find the solution for this. I searched 100's of ways in stackoverflow and I tried all of those way's but still same issue.
Can somebody please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Go to path /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php In this file find:

**$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);**

Replace with:

**$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));**

Comment: there is line containing this [ $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);]

Comment: this line is there   [ foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
                return true;
            } ]

Answer (score 0):

**core_config_data Table**

> **`Try This Query`**

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`=1 WHERE `path` = 'dev/static/sign';

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`=1 WHERE `path` = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';
```

Comment: where I have to write this query? sorry for this I'am new to magento.

Comment: Query Execute in Database

Comment: It's Working Or Not??

Comment: no friend not working. Im irritated with this. I think magento will not support windows machine. In magento site it clear that magento will support ubuntu and centos.